# Magento Onepage Checkout - Recalculate Shipping Quote

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I've got two independent extensions installed in Magento - one to calculate FedEx shipping costs via their API, and another to select the desired delivery date.  These two currently don't talk to each other, which means the FedEx shipping quotes always assume the package will be shipped the night you place the order.

The quote is being generated immediately before the Shipping Method renders.  When it does render, the delivery date block is also loaded in.  This means the user is selecting a delivery date AFTER the quotes have been generated.

**I essentially need some way to save the date and reload the Shipping Method tab, so that it regenerates the quotes using the provided date.**

**What is the best approach to making this work?**  I'm hoping I can do this without drastic changes to onepage - basically use as much of the existing JS and controller logic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you clearly have both steps tied together, your solution could be to try and ask the delivery date in address step (billing or shipping) and then making it available and understandable for your FedEx extension. Other possibility is to attach event listener to date field and on change will submit the data and reload the shipping method block

Comment: The second option is pretty much what I'm looking for.  I guess I'm just not sure of exactly how to make it reload the shipping method - is there some existing code I can use, or will I need to write some myself?

Comment: sure you can post your data with same method as billing or shipping address and set the step to reload